# addEditor: Sharing with non-Gmail emails

Tags: email, google-apps-script

I am working within NYU gmail in a spreadsheet (gmail within the nyu.edu domain). The script for addEditor seems to only work for @gmail addresses (even though I'm only logged into my NYU account/scripting from within that account). I have read some documentation that this is an issue, but does anyone know a workaround? In the code below, the emails are in line 2, and the docID is in line 10 of my spreadsheet. I have tried adding editors both via documentApp method--

```
 for (var i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++) {
    var eAddress = sh.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(sh.getRange(i, 10).getValue());
    doc.addEditor(eAddress)
  }
```

And via the Drive advanced service:

```
var eAddress = sh.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
var fileID = sh.getRange(i, 10).getValue();
Drive.Permissions.insert( 
    { 
      'role': 'writer', 
      'type': 'user', 
      'value': eAddress 
    }, 
    fileID, 
    { 
 'sendNotificationEmails': 'false' 
    });
```

Both methods only add editors who have gmail addresses (unfortunately, all my students have nyu addresses). Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Would setting it to domain with link work for your application?

```js
   // sets sharing to Domain with link - People in your domain who have the link can access. Sign-in required.
    sheet.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.DOMAIN_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion: this approach is equivalent to sharing a folder with the class and I was hoping for more precise sharing. NYU eventually enabled the addEditor commands within the domain.